# Error in plot of graph

Tags: r, plot, candlestick-chart

Professionals, could you help me with the plot of candle graph? I want to do that with the ggplot2. 
My data is:

```
               period bid_open bid_high bid_low bid_close ask_open ask_high 
1 2015-01-02 00:00:00  1.20860  1.20880 1.20860   1.20870  1.20890  1.20890 
2 2015-01-02 00:01:00  1.20870  1.20880 1.20865   1.20865  1.20880  1.20890 
3 2015-01-02 00:02:00  1.20865  1.20880 1.20865   1.20875  1.20875  1.20885 
4 2015-01-02 00:03:00  1.20875  1.20885 1.20875   1.20885  1.20885  1.20900 
5 2015-01-02 00:04:00  1.20885  1.20885 1.20880   1.20880  1.20895  1.20895 
6 2015-01-02 00:05:00  1.20880  1.20885 1.20880   1.20880  1.20890  1.20895
```

The end date is `2015-12-31`. So data frame has column with similar names (open, high, low, close), I use `grepl` to work with the needed column and then choose the first column (so there is two open - bid  and ask, and I choose the first one - may be the error is here?). For my function input is `x-data frame` and `start` and `end` as the initial and end points of plotting. R attempts to plot it but does not give the result and the plot. What's the problem in my code?

```
start <- "2015-10-28 20:58:00"
end <- "2015-12-31 20:58:00"
ggChartSeries <- function(x, start, end){

  open_col <- x[, grepl("open", names(x))]
  open_col=open_col[,1]
  close_col <- x[, grepl("close", names(x))]
  close_col=close_col[,1]
  high_col <- x[, grepl("high", names(x))]
  high_col=high_col[,1]
  low_col <- x[, grepl("low", names(x))]
  low_col=low_col[,1]


  date <- x[,1]
  open <- open_col
  high <- high_col
  low <- low_col
  close <- close_col

  xSubset <-data.frame('date'=date,'open'=open,'high'= high,'low'=low,'close'=close)

  xSubset$candleLower <- pmin(xSubset$open, xSubset$close)
  xSubset$candleMiddle <- (pmax(xSubset$open, xSubset$close)+pmin(xSubset$open, xSubset$close))/2
  xSubset$candleUpper <- pmax(xSubset$open, xSubset$close)
  xSubset$fill <- ''
  xSubset$fill[xSubset$open < xSubset$close] = 'white'
  xSubset$fill[xSubset$fill ==''] = 'red'

  #Trim Data
  xSubset <-subset(xSubset, xSubset$date > start & xSubset$date < end)

  g <- ggplot(xSubset, aes(x=date, lower=candleLower, middle=candleMiddle, upper=candleUpper, ymin=low, ymax=high),boxlwd=4) 
  g <- g + geom_boxplot(stat='identity', aes(group=date, fill=fill))
  g+scale_y_continuous(name = "Price")+theme_bw() +ggtitle("Candle Plot")

}
```

Comment: can you run `dput(data)` and write the answer here?

Comment: Now I understood, that I used very big time distance, now R plots this graph quickly. Thank you! But Now in the x scale R depicts only hours and minutes, however I used the time period 3 days. May be you know how to add day in the x scale?